# How to configure different versions of Ruby / any other software in self hosted agent?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have installed 3 different versions of Ruby in self hosted agent but i am unable to use them in my vsts task as required. The microsoft document suggests configuring "**Agent.ToolsDirectory**" but i am not sure how to configure it in the self hosted agents. Can anyone help me with descriptive steps on how to configure it so that i can use the vsts task : "Use Ruby Version task" on my self hosted agent

Comment: Could you configure “Agent.ToolsDirectory” successfully with my answer now?

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution Merlin i will try and surely let you know.

Comment: Hi, how are things going? Can you configured it successfully? Please let us know if there is any progress

Comment: i tried configuring the way you said also followed this article to configure the directory structure inside the agents but the tasks are still not picking up the Ruby versions: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/tools.md

Comment: Do i need to add environment variable : VSTS_TOOLS_PATH in the self hosted agents?

Answer (score 1):

> how to configure it in the self hosted agents?

**Agent.ToolsDirectory**, this is one of capabilities of pool which need you add it in the Org setting. So that while the pipeline executed, it will depend on it.

So, for configure it, just go **Org setting-->Agent pools**. Click the **agent pool** where your self host agent is which you have installed 3 different version ruby.

[image]

And then point to the agent, and open the **capabilities** tab and Click **Add capability**.

Input **Agent.ToolsDirectory** in the left blank, and add the **file path** where your ruby installed. For me, I installed it in the file **_work_tool** of my agent.

After these configured, you can use **Use Ruby Version task** to point out which version Ruby you want to use with self hosted.

Comment: Followed this tutorial: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops#how-can-i-configure-a-self-hosted-agent-to-use-this-task) and configured all the steps to install Ruby side by side versions - 2.4.6 and 2.5.5 as specified, restarted agent service on Virtual machine but still when i try to use the task it says : ##[error]Version spec > 2.4 for architecture %25s did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.
Although it exists . Do i need to do something else to make the agent pickup new changes?

Comment: @Arghya, did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: Yes @Oyvind i was missing a file - {platform}.complete should which is a 0 byte file that looks like x86.complete or x64.complete and just signifies the tool has been installed in the cache properly. Please follow the link in my first comment and you should be good.